# What is the difference between 7201 vs 7201 BEP Single Row Angular Contact Ball Bearings?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical, bearings

What does BEP mean when applied to types of ball bearings?

Comment: BEP is one of the possible codes, by the manufacturer (SKF), of design variations... It might be something subtle, like grade of precision or clearance/interference ... You'll have to dig through their pdf's. Somewhere there should be a part-number decoding guide. Also consider calling a salesperson

Comment: In practice, is there a difference between 6201 and 7201? I see the latter is much more expensive.

Comment: this should be its own question. per manufacturer website, 7201 = angular contact ; 6201 = deep groove  ;  there's a spectrum of ball bearing categories, which give names to how much axial vs radial load is allowed. the extreme ends are a *radial bearing* (no axial load), and a *thrust bearing* (no radial load). these tend to be more economical. In between, there's the types you have: *angular contact* bearings, for substantial axial load in one direction, and medium radial load,  and *deep groove* is substantial radial load, and medium axial load, in either direction. These tend to cost more